# Web Service clients

Tags: .net, web-services

I have a .net based asmx service and I trying to find out details on the clients that are currently using it.

Just wondering what is the best way to gather the information on things like the IP address of the client, the URL that is using my service and so on.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS logs with [LogParser](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en).

Comment: BTW this still doesn't resolve issue of actually detecting the website that is using my WS.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that, except for limited circumstances (like an Intranet), the IP address you receive may not be meaningful. It could be the IP address of a proxy server, or an address given out by a NAT device. If you need reliability, then you need to create value that is intended to identify the machine - IP addresses are explicitly not meant to identify machines.